# Not empty string constraint in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, constraints

Can I create a database constraint on a *TEXT* column in *SQLite* disallowing the value of the column to be empty string *""*?

I want to allow the column to be *null*, but disallow empty string.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Yes you can](http://sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#column-constraint):

```
sqlite> create table foo (bar TEXT, CHECK(bar <> ''));
sqlite> insert into foo values (NULL);
sqlite> insert into foo values ('bla');
sqlite> insert into foo values ('');
Error: constraint failed
```

Comment: What does `<>` mean?

Answer (score 6):

You can use a CHECK constraint (http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html):

```
SQLite version 3.5.9
Enter ".help" for instructions
sqlite> create table example(col, CHECK (col is null or length(col) > 0));
sqlite> insert into example values ('');
SQL error: constraint failed
sqlite> insert into example values (null);
sqlite> insert into example values ('sample');
sqlite> .nullvalue NULL
sqlite> select col from example;
NULL
sample
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know doesn't exist a similar constraint in SQLite, but maybe you can workaround with a **Trigger** that on **INSERT** and/or **UPDATE** automatically change the string empty in NULL.