# Why can I add null value to primary key in SQLite?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, sqlite, null

I have this code, you can try on [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7hbd5pqDhBkhbFNc8gdZJ5/0):

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE
( ID        INT,
  Name      VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  Age       INT,
  Dnumber   INT,
  Level     INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (ID, Name, Age, Dnumber, Level) VALUES(1,'Tom', 21, 2, 5);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (ID, Name, Age, Dnumber, Level) VALUES(2,'Lucky', 22, 2, 3);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (ID, Name, Age, Dnumber, Level) VALUES(NULL,'Blue', 22, 2, 3);
```

If I use SQLite, I can add the NULL value but it cannot if I use MySQL. I will get this error:

```
Schema Error: Error: ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR: Column 'ID' cannot be null
```

What is the reason why I can add it to SQLite?

Comment: I can't speak for SQLite but primary key column aren't nullable in any database engine I work with.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Yes, that right. I just don't know why SQLite allows it to be null.

Comment: @huy What about checking in the [documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html)? Section 3.5

Comment: You should use INTEGER, not INT, for a primary key affinity in sqlite - see https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid

Comment: To be precise `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, as documentation says in link for section 3.5. INT is just shorthand for INTEGER, but that phrase has another meaning syntactically and should be read as one element.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to @astentx for the advice. I checked the [documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#the_primary_key) and it said that:

> According to the SQL standard, PRIMARY KEY should always imply NOT NULL. Unfortunately, due to a bug in some early versions, this is not the case in SQLite. Unless the column is an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY or the table is a WITHOUT ROWID table or the column is declared NOT NULL, SQLite allows NULL values in a PRIMARY KEY column. SQLite could be fixed to conform to the standard, but doing so might break legacy applications. Hence, it has been decided to merely document the fact that SQLite allowing NULLs in most PRIMARY KEY columns.

Comment: I can't believe they allowed null values to lurk around in primary keys, using the legacy excuse. Not conforming to the standard simply creates more confusion for everyone.

Comment: @Alin Gabriel Arhip agreed this seems outrageous.  Isn't that was versioning is for?

Comment: Omg this is bad, LOL.

Answer (score 2):

In SQLite basically, you can add `NULL` to `PRIMARY KEY` columns but you cannot add `NULL` to `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` and `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` columns even if they don't have `NOT NULL` constraint. [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28925736/not-null-constraint-not-working-on-the-primary-key-column-in-sqlite-android/77227303#77227303) explains it more.

Answer (score -2):

PRIMARY KEY (ID) isn't allowed to store NULL for MySQL, if i remember correctly.
So your ID column can't store NULL values.

Comment: Please provide an answer for the question "What is the reason why I can add it to SQLite?" - the OP already stated that `NULL`  is not allowed in MySQL

Answer (score -3):

ID field is the primary key(a primary index exists on the field), that is why the field cannot accept the null values. It should have not null unique values.

Official Doc:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/constraint-primary-key.html

Comment: Please provide an answer for the question "What is the reason why I can add it to SQLite?" - the OP already stated that `NULL`  is not allowed in MySQL