# How to display `Null` (SQLite)

Tags: database, sqlite, null, command, database-table

On **SQLite**, I displayed **the table "user"** as shown below but **"Null"** is not displayed so I cannot differentiate between **"Null"** and **Blank(Empty String)**:

```
sqlite> .header on
sqlite> .mode box
sqlite> select * from user;
┌────┬─────────────────┐
│ id │      name       │
├────┼─────────────────┤
│ 1  │ Steve Jobs      │
│ 2  │                 │ <- Null
│ 3  │                 │ <- Null
│ 4  │ Bill Gates      │
│ 5  │                 │ <- Blank(Empty String)
│ 6  │ Mark Zuckerberg │
└────┴─────────────────┘
```

Are there any ways to display **"Null"**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This command below can set what to show for `NULL` values:

```
.nullvalue <String>
```

So, set `NULL` as shown below:

```
.nullvalue NULL
```

Then, `NULL` is displayed for `NULL` values as shown below:

```
sqlite> .headers on
sqlite> .mode box
sqlite> SELECT * FROM person;
┌────┬─────────────────┐
│ id │      name       │
├────┼─────────────────┤
│ 1  │ Steve Jobs      │
│ 2  │ NULL            │ <- NULL
│ 3  │ NULL            │ <- NULL
│ 4  │ Bill Gates      │
│ 5  │                 │ <- Blank(Empty String)
│ 6  │ Mark Zuckerberg │
└────┴─────────────────┘
```

Next, set `This is NULL.` as shown below:

```
.nullvalue "This is NULL."
```

Then, `This is NULL` is displayed for `NULL` values as shown below:

```
sqlite> .headers on
sqlite> .mode box
sqlite> SELECT * FROM person;
┌────┬─────────────────┐
│ id │      name       │
├────┼─────────────────┤
│ 1  │ Steve Jobs      │
│ 2  │ This is NULL.   │ <- NULL
│ 3  │ This is NULL.   │ <- NULL
│ 4  │ Bill Gates      │
│ 5  │                 │ <- Blank(Empty String)
│ 6  │ Mark Zuckerberg │
└────┴─────────────────┘
```

And, these commands below can show the details of the command `.nullvalue`:

```
.help .nullvalue
```

Or:

```
.help nullvalue
```

Then, this is how it looks like below:

```
sqlite> .help .nullvalue  
.nullvalue STRING        Use STRING in place of NULL values
```